# Issue trying to deploy KeystoneJS using Digital Ocean

Tags: unicode, digital-ocean, slug, keystonejs, deploying

I'm getting the below error when I try to deploy my Keystonejs website. It works when I run it locally. However using digital ocean on: 512 MB Memory / 20 GB Disk / LON1 - Ubuntu node v4.4.0 on 14.04 it gives ...

> node keystone.js

{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'unicode/category/So'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at symbols (/root/vanillakeystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/keystone-utils/node_modules/slug/slug.js:6:16)
    at /root/vanillakeystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/keystone-utils/node_modules/slug/slug.js:199:5
    at Object. (/root/vanillakeystone/node_modules/keystone/node_modules/keystone-utils/node_modules/slug/slug.js:212:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I too get it some time.
Whenever I get I run this command.

```
node node_modules/unicode/install.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually go into your `node_modules` folder and delete the unicode module. Then, go back to your project directory where you're running `node keystone.js` and type npm install unicode.

Then run your `node keystone.js` command again.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is create a Docker image with my Keystone project, so that I don't have that kind of compatibility issues:

https://v5.keystonejs.com/guides/deployment